# Hold the Scheduled Job Execution in SCDF until the previous job execution completes

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-batch, openshift, spring-cloud-dataflow

I'm running SCDF in Openshift environment. I'm scheduling a Spring batch job to run once in every 5 minutes. Sometimes the job may run for more than 5 minutes. In that scenario, is it possible to hold the next scheduled job execution until the previous one completes its execution?

We don't want to change frequency of job execution also the interval.

**Update 1:**
Recently I found that with Kubernetes cronjob we can add `concurrencyPolicy=forbid` to stop the next job executions from happening if the previous one is still running.

I'm looking for equivalent configuration in SCDF.

Thanks.

Comment: Why do you need that? Is there any dependency between jobs? This is a sign jobs are not designed to be completely independent from each others.

Comment: Its a single Job which is scheduled to run every 5 minutes. And process 1000's of records in a table. when the second job execution starts before the first job execution gets completed the second job reader may read old value or both jobs instance may try to update the same record in the same table

Comment: Each job instance should process a fixed, uniquely identifiable data set (for restartability  and for job instance identification reasons). It seems that this is not the case for you. You need to find a way to make each job instance process a distinct set of records.

Comment: If job execution-1 completes successfully, one of the status column will be updated with proper status and next job execution won't pick them up. The issue is when the first execution crosses the 5 Minute interval and the status column update is still pending. So they next job also picks the same records. With a Normal @scheduled in spring boot, the next job execution won't start until the first one gets completed provided it's single threaded application.

Comment: Which scheduler are you using?

Comment: SCDF inbuilt scheduler for kubernetes

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at property  `spring.cloud.task.single-instance-enabled`. Документация - [Spring-cloud-task#features-single-instance-enabled](https://docs.spring.io/spring-cloud-task/docs/current/reference/#features-single-instance-enabled)
This prevents two tasks with the same name from running.
I checked on SCDF (2.6.1) and when running two identical tasks got the error:

```
Caused by: org.springframework.cloud.task.listener.TaskExecutionException: Task with name "timestamp-task" is already running.
    at org.springframework.cloud.task.configuration.SingleInstanceTaskListener.lockTask(SingleInstanceTaskListener.java:121) ~[spring-cloud-task-core-2.2.3.RELEASE.jar!/:2.2.3.RELEASE]
    ... 31 common frames omitted
```